# ShellExecute in suspend mode

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

Createprocess API has a option to create a process with CREATE_SUSPENDED flag. Similarly, is there any possiblity in ShellExecute APIs to create the process in suspended state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell execute while spawning a process is not invoking createprocess in windows 7. But that's opposite in windows 2008. Hence implemented wine code for shellexecute in win7 and made to work via createprocess for my application.

Answer (score 3):

No. ShellExecute doesn't have to imply a process is launched - it's used to perform "shell operations" such as "open" or "print", which *may* lead to a new process being created.

Comment: In vista/2008, If I execute shellexecute the process opens via createprocess api. Howerver, In windows 7, If I execute a shellexecute statement, it doesnot process via createprocess. I wonder about the way it spans the process. Do you have any idea Erik.

Comment: All of the process spawning API's eventually end up in `NtCreateProcess` as far as I'm aware. But, as said, ShellExecute doesn't always have to create a process.

Comment: All process spawning function will not pass through NTcreateprocess. Most of the apis pass via createprocess api. Createprocess not necessarily have to pass via ntcreateprocess. I found lot of create prrocess calls not passing via ntcreateprocess. Similarly Shellexecute creates process few times as you said. Those process creation  passed via createprocess api in 2008 environments. However In windows 7 it doesnot depend on createprocess api.